# Consuming contents of declare_directory

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I have rule A implemented with a macro that uses declare_directory to produce a set of files:

```
output = ctx.actions.declare_directory("selected")
```

Names of those files are not known in advance. The implementation returns the directory created by declare_directory with the following:

```
return DefaultInfo(
    files = depset([output]),
)
```

Rule A is included in "srcs" attribute of rule B. Rule B is also implemented with a macro. Unfortunately the list of files passed to B implementation through "srcs" attribute only contains the "selected" directory created by rule A instead of files residing in that directory.

I know that Args class supports expansion of directories so I could pass names of all files in "selected" directory to a single action. What I need, however, is a separate action for every individual file for parallelism and caching. What is the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the intended use cases of directory outputs (called TreeArtifacts in the implementation), and it's implemented using ActionTemplate:
https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/c2100ad420618bb53754508da806b5624209d9be/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/actions/ActionTemplate.java#L24-L57

However, this is not exposed to Starlark, and has only a couple usages currently, in the Android rules [AndroidBinary.java](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/68ffdd2784caea06f8d3554cc09991cb6197b53e/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/rules/android/AndroidBinary.java#L1654) and C++ rules [CcCompilationHelper.java](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/a859caac864db0c96fb8b9746d6708ea4be6fd72/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/rules/cpp/CcCompilationHelper.java#L1578). The Android rules and C++ rules are going to be migrated over to Starlark, so this functionality might eventually be made available in Starlark, but I'm not sure of any concrete timelines. It would probably be good to file a feature request on Github.